# Android: Skipped 41 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I'm really struggling to get my head round this thread thing. The below code is my mainactivity, I am just trying to test if my sqlite database is functioning by running a simple query to display a recipe.
Currently the app just runs the main screen but nothing else works. What can I do to get this working?
I can provide further code/snippets if requested. Thank you
package com.stu54259.plan2cook;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar;
import com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView;
import com.synnapps.carouselview.ImageListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CarouselView carouselView;
    int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.avocado_salad, R.drawable.chicken_tikka_curry, R.drawable.turkey_taco_bowls};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpBottomAppBar();

        carouselView = findViewById(R.id.recipeImage);
        carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);
        carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);


        findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Create Recipe Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        GridView gv = findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gv.setAdapter(new SetImageAdapter(this));

    }
        ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
                imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
            }
        };

    private void setUpBottomAppBar() {
        BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
        setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);
        Log.d("appbar setup", "yes");
        bottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.recipes:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recipes clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Intent", "clicked ");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Recipe.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.shoppingList:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Shopping List clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
   /* @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_primary, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }*/
}
```

**Logcat**

```
Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Recipe.java

```
    package com.stu54259.plan2cook;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.RecipeList;
import com.stu54259.plan2cook.database.DatabaseManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Recipe extends MainActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ImageView recipeImage;
    TextView descriptionText, courseText, servingsText, costText, caloriesText, methodText;
    RecyclerView listIngredient;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String search_name, selectQuery;
    Cursor c;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapterRecipe;
    List<RecipeList> itemRecipe = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);
        //search_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
        search_name = "Speedy chicken couscous";
        //recyclerview Recipe
        adapterRecipe = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, itemRecipe);
        listIngredient = findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        listIngredient.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        listIngredient.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        listIngredient.setAdapter(adapterRecipe);
        loadRecipe();

    }
    public void loadRecipe() {
        itemRecipe.clear();
        db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
        String selectQuery = "";
        selectQuery = selectQuery + "SELECT A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " +
                "FROM TABLE_QUANTITY JOIN TABLE_INGREDIENT ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name";

        c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RecipeList recipeList = new RecipeList();
                recipeList.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("COL_ID")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_amount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY")));
                recipeList.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_NAME")));
                recipeList.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_DESCRIPTION")));
                itemRecipe.add(recipeList);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }

    }
}
```

**Recyclerview adapter**

```
package com.stu54259.plan2cook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.RecipeList;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<RecipeList> itemRecipe;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<RecipeList> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.itemRecipe = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.myTextView.setText(itemRecipe.get(position).getIngredient_amount());
        holder.myTextView.setText(itemRecipe.get(position).getMeasurement_name());
        holder.myTextView.setText(itemRecipe.get(position).getIngredient_name());
        holder.myTextView.setText(itemRecipe.get(position).getDescription());

    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemRecipe.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }


    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: The skipped frames just means something slow is happening on your main thread - ideally it wants to get everything done in under 16ms (so it can maintain 60 frames per second) but if you're doing anything heavy - like reading or writing files, or waiting for a network request - then it can block the thread and you end up skipping frames while you're waiting. But it can come down to an emulator not running well too. What isn't actually working?

Comment: It doesn't even get as far as launching Recipe.java from what I can tell, I have toast messages on the bottom app bar which never get displayed.

Comment: Does it open the Recipe activity? You'll see the first activity getting replaced. Also you're creating your ``adapterRecipe`` adapter with an empty item list and setting it on the ``RecyclerView`` before you've populated it with recipes - you can call ``notifyDatasetChanged`` on the adapter to make it update, but usually you'd grab your data before you create the adapter. If your activity is loading but it's empty, that might be why. (Also in ``onBindViewHolder`` you're setting the text on the same ``TextView`` four times!)

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean about setting the same textview 4 times, I was trying to set  the columns data. Not sure what i've done or how to change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try making the DB calls in an `AsyncTask`

```
AsyncTask getRecipesTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            loadRecipe();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //TODO update adapter with new items
        }
    };
```

And in `onCreate`
Replace the call to `loadRecipe()` with `getRecipesTask.execute()`

```
public class Recipe extends MainActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ImageView recipeImage;
    TextView descriptionText, courseText, servingsText, costText, caloriesText, methodText;
    RecyclerView listIngredient;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String search_name, selectQuery;
    Cursor c;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapterRecipe;
    List<RecipeList> itemRecipe = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);
        //search_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
        search_name = "Speedy chicken couscous";
        //recyclerview Recipe
        adapterRecipe = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);
        listIngredient = findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        listIngredient.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        listIngredient.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        listIngredient.setAdapter(adapterRecipe);
        getRecipesTask.execute();

    }
    public void loadRecipe() {
        itemRecipe.clear();
        db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
        String selectQuery = "";
        selectQuery = selectQuery + "SELECT A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " +
                "FROM TABLE_QUANTITY JOIN TABLE_INGREDIENT ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name";

        c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RecipeList recipeList = new RecipeList();
                recipeList.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("COL_ID")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_amount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY")));
                recipeList.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_NAME")));
                recipeList.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_DESCRIPTION")));
                itemRecipe.add(recipeList);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }

    }

    AsyncTask getRecipesTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            loadRecipe();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            adapterRecipe.setItems(itemRecipe);
        }
    };
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what your adapter looks like but trying something like this:

Probably `setItems` could be something like in the Adapter

```
public void setItems(List<Recipe> items) {
   this.items = items;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, where would I position the loadrecipe function? I'm very new to this.

Comment: Can you share what your `RecyclerViewAdapter` looks like?
`new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, itemRecipe);`

Comment: Shared that also getting Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Comment: Don't worry too much about random logcat messages! There's a lot of spam in there, especially on an emulator. And you can keep the ``loadRecipe``function where it is, it's just that instead of calling it from ``onCreate``, you'd execute that ``AsyncTask`` in ``onCreate`` instead. It will go off and load all the stuff into a list in the background, and then in ``onPostExecute`` you do something with it - Cameron's suggesting having a function in your adapter that you can call with the items list, which updates the adapter to display the contents